# Performing a click over other apps in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, accessibilityservice

Why is there still no clear answer to this question? I've read every single post I had found and tried every solution, but my little brain cannot get this to work. I had tried creating MyAccessibilityService, which looks like this:

```
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    private var myAccessibilityServiceInstance: MyAccessibilityService? = null

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        myAccessibilityServiceInstance = this
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        myAccessibilityServiceInstance = null
        return super.onUnbind(intent)
    }

    fun getInstance(): MyAccessibilityService? {
        return myAccessibilityServiceInstance
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        println("Worked, I guess..")
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        println("Didn't work, I guess..")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val command = intent?.getStringExtra("command")
        when (command) {
            "click" -> {
                val accessibilityService: MyAccessibilityService? = getInstance();
                if (accessibilityService != null) {
                    val x = intent.getIntExtra("x", 0)
                    val y = intent.getIntExtra("y", 0)
                    click(x, y)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    fun click(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
        val builder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        builder.addStroke(GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 1))
        dispatchGesture(builder.build(), null, null)
    }
}
```

And then tried calling it once a button is pressed, using an Intent, like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MyAccessibilityService::class.java)
intent.putExtra("command", "click")
intent.putExtra("x", 323)
intent.putExtra("y", 382)
startService(intent)
```

But, once pressing the button, nothing happens! Can someone help me figure this out (without destroying this little bit of will to live left in me, if possible)?